# Hibernate Annotation to avoid duplicate entry to db based on value in multiple columns

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Is there any annotation in hibernate which i can use to find out if an entry that matches multiple fields is already in db or not. For now i am using INSERT IGNORE statement to achieve the same. I want to do it based on multiple columns not on a single column.

For eg i am having a table in which there are three columns.
title,author and description and price. I dont a repeated entry which exactly matches the above mentioned four fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniqueConstraints` property of  `@Table` annotation for your purpose:

```
@Table(name = "book", uniqueConstraints = {
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"title", "author", "description", "price"})
})
```

It specifies that a unique constraint is to be included in the generated DDL for a primary table.

For instance, if you have a book with **title=1**, **author=1**, **description=1** and **price=1** in the book table, it will throw an exception when someone inserts a new row with the same values.